# Does any train or bus company charge a no-show fee, or is that fee specific to some airlines?

Tags: air-travel, trains, buses, fees-and-charges

Airlines sometimes have a no-show fee in case someone pays for a flight ticket but doesn't show up to the flight.

I don't recall seeing such a fee for trains or buses. Does any train or bus company charge a no-show fee, or is that fee specific to airlines?

I'm asking as this would help me identify which potential fees I should be aware of when purchasing train or bus tickets.

---

Replies to comments:

> The whole idea [of charging a no show fee] is absurd. Suppose I buy a bottle of beer but don't drink it. Will the company surcharge me for not using their product? – [Weather Vane](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane) [7 mins ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166232/does-any-train-or-bus-company-charge-a-no-show-fee-or-is-that-fee-specific-to-a?noredirect=1#comment413807_166232)

Some airlines companies do have a no-show fee, e.g. https://www.qatarairways.com/tradepartner/en/bookingnticketing/Penalties-and-Charges.html: "No-Show Charge: The charge made by reason of the failure of a passenger to use reserved accommodation, either through failure to arrive at the airport at the time fixed by the carrier, or through arriving improperly documented or otherwise not ready to travel on flight."

> the airline has been paid for the seat already, and can now re-sell it; that's much easier (and more significant) money. – [DavidSupportsMonica](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/76708/davidsupportsmonica) [3 hours ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166232/does-any-train-or-bus-company-charge-a-no-show-fee-or-is-that-fee-specific-to-a#comment413796_166232)

No-show fee [!=](https://www.qatarairways.com/tradepartner/en/bookingnticketing/Penalties-and-Charges.html) cancellation fee.

> How would a railway prove you weren’t on the train? And I suspect its probably against EU rules. Afaik they permit a passenger to give up their travel plans at their own discretion. – [Krist van Besien](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6047/krist-van-besien) [5 mins ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166232/does-any-train-or-bus-company-charge-a-no-show-fee-or-is-that-fee-specific-to-s#comment413840_166232)

Some railways check when you enter e.g. high-speed train in China.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Does any train or bus company charge a no-show fee, or is that fee specific to airlines?

Not in the European Union, as [Krist van Besien](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6047/krist-van-besien) mentioned in the [comments](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166232/does-any-train-or-bus-company-charge-a-no-show-fee-or-is-that-fee-specific-to-s#comment413842_166232), for 2 reasons:

> 1. Except for Eurostar, [no railways can prove you weren’t on the train] in Europe.  [Krist van Besien](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6047/krist-van-besien) [1 hour ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166232/does-any-train-or-bus-company-charge-a-no-show-fee-or-is-that-fee-specific-to-s#comment413842_166232)
> 2. EU rules don’t permit no-show fees. So you have part of hour answer there. – [Krist van Besien](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6047/krist-van-besien) [1 hour ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166232/does-any-train-or-bus-company-charge-a-no-show-fee-or-is-that-fee-specific-to-s#comment413842_166232)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a major misunderstanding - a no-show fee is *not* an *additional fee* you are supposed to pay, but a reduction of the value of your ticket.
In other words, if you buy a ticket for $ 300, and don’t show up, your remaining ticket value is not $ 300, but a *reduced* amount - reduced by the no-show fee.

If you have a ticket for a train or bus (or a concert or a football game), and don’t show up, the remaining value of your ticket is simply zero. You could call this a “100%-no-show-fee”; they simply don’t use that term.

Comment: thanks, if I buy a 1-way ticket with some QR, with ticket price = 500 USD and no-show fee = 200 USD, does this mean I can receive 300 USD if I don't show up? I had assumed  I wouldn't be able to get anything.

Comment: No, it means your “remaining ticket value” is 300$. You can use those as payment for another ticket you buy from this airline. (“Rule #5: Once you have their money, you never give it back”)

Comment: Looks like sometimes you do have to pay extra because of a no-how: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/166244/1810

Comment: That's a completely different thing - he was trying (maybe unintentionally) to play the hidden-city ticket game. He could of course not pay anything and walk away, but he wanted the remainder of his ticket become valid again.

Comment: That's the same thing: if someone doesn't show up to the airport in time, that's called a no-show. No idea why you assume the passenger is "playing games": they may have plenty of other reasons for the no-show. Therefore your answer is incorrect.