# Does Qatar Airways have a no-show fee in case a passenger misses a flight (assuming the passenger only purchased a flight ticket and nothing else)?

Tags: air-travel, fees-and-charges, qatar-airways

https://www.qatarairways.com/tradepartner/en/bookingnticketing/Penalties-and-Charges.html states:

> No-Show Charge: The charge made by reason of the failure of a passenger to use reserved accommodation, either through failure to arrive at the airport at the time fixed by the carrier, or through arriving improperly documented or otherwise not ready to travel on flight.

From my understanding, this means that Qatar Airways may charge a no-show fee in case a passenger misses a flight (even if the passenger only purchased a flight ticket and nothing else, i.e. didn't book any hotel).

However I read some [comments](https://archive.ph/qQae2) that contradict my understanding:

> - To me, it is quite clear that the hotel will want to be paid for accomodation you reserved, but did not pay for, because it could have been used by someone else. The flight has been paid for in advance, but the room was only reserved. So it is no-show as applicable to the accomodation, not the flight. – [Weather Vane](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane) [10 mins ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166232/does-any-train-or-bus-company-charge-a-no-show-fee-or-is-that-fee-specific-to-a?noredirect=1#comment413819_166232)

Does Qatar Airways have a no-show fee in case a passenger misses a flight (assuming the a passenger only purchased a flight ticket and nothing else)?

Comment: Will you please remove the quoted comment about buying beer, which was in relation to the previous, but quite different, question? It is not relevant to this spin-off question.

Comment: @WeatherVane the beer comment was in the same issue (getting charged for not using something that one has already paid for). I've quote here because I had the same reaction the day I discovered no-show fees.

Comment: No, that was in relation to buying a bus or train ticket. That has nothing to do with paying for reserved accommodation before or after a flight.

Comment: The comments are locked for now, to avoid re-posting of comments which had been flagged and removed for the flagged reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up leveling the question a bit: Yes airlines will try to charge you extra for NOT using a service you have already fully paid for.

Example: I was flying BOS-> LON, LON->FRA, FRA->BOS. I couldn't take the LON->FRA leg and cancelled it. United charged me a $250 cancellation fee for NOT taking a flight segment that was already paid for and that was worth maybe $100.

This practice makes really not much sense. Going back to the beer analogy: it's like going to a bar, buying a beer, paying for it and then getting fined if you don't actually drink the beer.

Of course, most passengers really don't want to pay that so the airlines can only get away with it if they have some means to enforce the payment. These typically are

1. Cancelling any remaining legs on the ticket (which was my problem).
2. If applicable: withholding any residual value of the ticket, i.e. refunds, travel credit, etc.
3. Revoking status, miles and/or privileges for frequent flyers.
4. In rare occasions actually suing a passenger. There were a few lawsuits involving "hidden city ticketing" but so far no court has sided with the airlines: "If you are making bizarre pricing rules you can't complain about passengers trying to take advantage of them".

So if this is the last leg of your ticket and the residual value (if any) on the ticket is smaller than the no-show fee, you really don't need to pay anything.

Comment: Thanks for the great information!

Comment: The practice makes sense (to airlines) because airlines want to protect their revenue models, and that depends on not allowing people to play certain types of games with airline tickets. For example, United may have decided that a BOS-LON-FRA roundtrip should be cheaper than BOS-LON (perhaps they're competing with a nonstop option for the FRA market). What they don't want people to do is book BOS-LON-FRA tickets when they really only want to travel to London, as that would mean selling both London fares for less and a bunch of canceled seats to FRA they'd have to find someone else to fill.

Comment: That said, besides going after a handful of people who were clearly trying to do hidden city ticketing, I've never heard of an airline trying to actively collect a special fee under normal "I booked this ticket for legitimate reasons and now my plans changed and I want to change my flight" circumstances. They'll just impose the regular change fee in that case, and if your ticket has any residual value, you can apply that toward your new tickets (which may be quite expensive if they're last-minute bookings). That's not a no-show fee, but just a normal change fee.

Answer (score 4):

If you read further in the linked pages, specifically the 'Changes (Reissuance)' and 'Cancel & Refund' sections, it's clear that the No-show fee is not some sort of extra fee but is for when you want to make a change or get a refund.  In particular see the tables in 'Cancel & Refund'.

As an aside, I don't believe 'accomodation' refers to a hotel in this case but to your spot on the plane.